# Spring boot - Test classes not letting go of database connections after finishing

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, performance, testing

I have a Spring Boot application where I need to test everything. I have run into this problem.

When I launch my tests (for example from **Gitlab** pipeline), tests are running fast from the beginning. But the more tests are done, the slower it gets. Loading Spring application context for another test class gets slower and slower. I have also found out, that during the tests, **database connections stays active** and application lets go of them **after all of the tests are finished**, even though **most of the classes have already finished a long time ago**. Have anyone run into this problem before and found solution for it please?

My annotations used in tests:

```
// Service test class example
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import({SomeService.class})
@Sql("classpath:testdata/some_test_data.sql")
public class SomeServiceTest {
```

```
// Controller test class example
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"some.package.with.tests"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Sql("classpath:testdata/some_test_data.sql")
public class SomeControllerTest {
```

Comment: I can't be certain from what you have shared thus far, but it sounds like you are starting multiple different application contexts (this will happen when you tests have different configuration) and each context is creating a pool of DB connections. Those contexts are cached (to allow reuse across tests with the same configuration) and won't be closed until the cache fills up or the JVM shuts down. It sounds like you're seeing the latter.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Do you see any problem in these annotations? Controller tests configuration is pretty much the same in whole project (only Sql files are different of course). In Service tests, of course Sql files, but here are also different classes in Import annotation (but there is a possibility of replacing it with ComponentScan annotation, just like in Controller tests, but I guess it would make load time longer).

Comment: Those two test classes will create two different contexts. If you have many more with different configuration then that's probably the cause of your problem. If you can't use common configuration across your test classes to minimise the number of contexts that are created, you can use `@DirtiesContext` to prevent caching. Alternatively, you could tune the connection pools to reduce the number of connections they create. 1 is probably sufficient as your tests are likely to be single-threaded.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson half of the problem is solved thanks to `@DirtiesContext`. After all tests in class are done, it lets go of the DB connections. However, another problem is still there. Application contexts still seems to be active, because the more tests are done, the slower it gets. I also got java Out of memory exception now. I am using the annotation like this `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`. Any idea, what could go wrong please?

Comment: No, sorry. Not from what you've shared thus far. I'd need to see enough to reproduce the problem to diagnose that one I think. It sound like you have a memory leak somewhere. A profiler may help you in identifying the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem with two steps:

**Step 1: DirtiesContext annotation** - This released DB connections after finishing tests from a specific class, so if I set `maximum-pool-size: 5` it would now use only those 5 connections.

Usage:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

**Step 2: Increasing memory for tests** - I also had to increase memory for Unit tests so I wouldn't get `OutOfMemoryException`. `MAVEN_OPTS` didn't work for me, so I had to use and configure plugin for this in **pom.xml**.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After this, my test pipeline time was much faster. From about **20-30 minutes** before, it now took **8 minutes**.

Thank you very much @AndyWilkinson for your good advices

**EDIT!!!!**
After this, my tests got coverage 0% reported on Sonar. After spending some time searching, I have found solution also for this:

**Step 3: Define property sonar.surefire.argLine**

```
<properties>
  ...
  <sonar.surefire.argLine>-Xmx2048m</sonar.surefire.argLine>
</properties>
```

**Step 4: Rewrite the plugin**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine} ${sonar.surefire.argLine}</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem here was, that **jacoco** plugin needs to have access to **surefire**'s *argLine*, but after you add it manually, it is no longer possible. That's why I had to add `@{argLine}`, which **jacoco** uses. `${sonar.surefire.argLine}` is just for better code appearance, so I could have `-Xmx2048m` argument with other defined properties.